# Import-WdsInstallImage : An install image could not be found in the image file

Tags: powershell, wds

I am trying to import install images into WDS.
However I get the following error:

```
Import-WdsInstallImage : An install image could not be found in the image file.
At line:3 char:1
+ Import-WdsInstallImage -ImageGroup 'Win2019' -ImageName $ImageName -P ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_WdsInstallImage:root/cimv2/MSFT_WdsInstallImage) [Import-WdsInstallImage], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 0xC111010E,Import-WdsInstallImage
```

And with WDSUTIL /Add-Image I get an error too.

I figured out that the image names I provide are wrong.
I use the following command lines to get image names:

```
Get-WindowsImage -ImagePath X:\Sources\install.wim
```

or

```
dism /get-imageinfo /imagefile:X:\Sources\install.wim
```

Unfortunately both command lines are returning the same image names:

- Windows Server 2019 Standard
- Windows Server 2019 Standard (Desktop Experience)
- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter (Desktop Experience)

I finally find the right names by importing images with the WDS console, and those name must be:

- Windows Server 2019 SERVERSTANDARDCORE
- Windows Server 2019 SERVERSTANDARD
- Windows Server 2019 SERVERDATACENTERCORE
- Windows Server 2019 SERVERDATACENTERCORE

How can I find those names with the command line instead of having to import them first with the console?

Comment: If the names include spaces, you may want to add quotes around the variable.

Comment: Thank you but I already done that. I even passed the image name from the Get-WindowsImage cmdlet to the Import-WdsInstallImage cmdlet to avoid this problem of space.

Comment: Is there another name listed if you run Get-Member on the output of Get-WindowsImage?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried both Format-List * -Force and Get-Member -Force to display possible hidden properties, but there are none.

Comment: The Get-WindowsImage is supposed to give the correct names. Here is how it should be: https://powershell.org/forums/topic/import-wim-image-to-wds/ However, even when trying with a genuine 2012R2 ISO downloaded from Microsoft I don't have the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with Windows 2019.

Whichever ISO (I tried Win 2012R2, Win 2016 and Win 2019) you connect or mount to a Win 2019 computer, the `Get-WindowsImage` cmdlet and the `Dism.exe` tool return the image names in the following format:

- Windows Server 2019 Standard
- Windows Server 2019 Standard (Desktop Experience)
- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter
- Windows Server 2019 Datacenter (Desktop Experience)

**These image names CANNOT be used to import images into WDS with the `Import-WdsInstallImage` cmdlet or with the `Dism.exe` tool.**

When you connect the same ISO to a Win 2012R2 or Win 2016 computer, the `Get-WindowsImage` cmdlet and the `Dism.exe` tool return the image names in the following format:

- Windows Server 2019 SERVERSTANDARDCORE
- Windows Server 2019 SERVERSTANDARD
- Windows Server 2019 SERVERDATACENTERCORE
- Windows Server 2019 SERVERDATACENTERCORE

**These image names CAN be used to import images into WDS with the `Import-WdsInstallImage` cmdlet or with the `Dism.exe` tool.**

### Conclusion:

As a workaround, connect your ISO to a Win 2012R2 or Win 2016 server in order to get the correct image name.